# How to resize combobox for ChangeListener when searching in javafx?

Tags: java, search, combobox, javafx-8, dropdown

When searching for a particular word in a combobox in JavaFX application, the dropdown is expanding more than usual combobox.

[image: Searchable combobox]

Below image is a normal combobox dropdown if I do not search for a particular item.

[image]

How can I make a searchable dropdown that is the same as the normal dropdown?

Comment: checkbox.prefWidthProperty().bind(<size>);

Comment: Thanks Akash!!!! but m confused..how can i declare size in bind()?? we cant declare bind(200) like this!!